# Risk bounds for Poisson regression

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, references, poisson-distribution, loss-functions

Defining risk of the estimator as the expected square loss,
is there any work discussing the non-asymptotic risk bounds for Poisson regression based on 
maximum likelihood estimate (MLE)?